# Manually edit .config for Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm trying to do some security research and I need to force set or manually set some options in the kernel's `.config` naturally it would be things like stack protectors, rwx and kernel aslr. I've been trying to manually edit the .config and then do a `make olddefconfig` but when I check the .config after doing that the options are changed back? Is there a proper way to set these options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't advise editing .config, but if you do, you'd probably start `make oldconfig`.  I know that leaves my old settings - when they don't conflict with the new kernel.

Comment: I tried this and it still "fixes" some options. Is there perhaps some make flag i need to prevent scripts from resetting them you think?

Comment: Okay I think I know why this is discouraged now, obviously some options depend on others one can learn this from the fs/Kconfig, mm/Kconfig etc for each folder. I've editted these and it seem to have the changes stick.